# Update a nested array in mongoose using javascript array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have issues updating a `mixed type` field in mongoose schema. This is not the best schema setup
but I have reasons seting it up this way. Now I want to perform `javascript array-like` 
operations such as `push`. I want to have access to the index of the current doc being iterated in the nested arrays, on the `tags`
field. Like so:

Mongoose schema

```
let user = {
    name : String,
    email : String,
    tags : []
}
```

The `tags` field is dynamically generated on creating the user, and I ended up with something like this
after inserting the user into db

```
tags : [ 
        [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}, ...], 
        [...], 
        [...], 
        [...], 
        [...] 
    ]
```

What I want to achieve - push a new document to the nested array the "javascript way"

```
user.tags[0].forEach(obj, index){
    // Do some operations here with obj and index
    // I don't know how to update a nested array with the mongo $push operator that is why I am falling back to the `js array push` method

    let newObj = { foo: bar }
    user.tags[0].push(newObj)
    user.save()
}
```

After testing with postman, it's showing that the operation was successful and returns 
an inserted item, but I observe two problems:

1. It is not persistent to db, but at the same time my response on postman looks like so:

```
{
    name : bar,
    email : foo,
    tags : [
        [{ foo : bar}], // from the last push operation I did
        [],
        [],
        []...
        ...
    ]
}
```

2. Subsequent `push` operations to any array index (e.g 0th index) replaces the current object instead of appending it:
   `user.tags[0].push(obj)` ===> this replaces the first object (in the postman response of course and not db because it seems not to be persistent)

Any help how to achieve this will be greatly appretiated

I am just learning these things, any better approach to solve the same problem is highly welcomed, thank you. :)

Comment: can you specify the final output you want to achieve with example?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found a solution from here:
[Freecodecamp forum](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/mongoose-save-is-not-working/100836/4)

I was missing the `user.markModified("nameOfFieldToUpdate")` line. After adding this line before the `user.save()` solves the issue.